# Filtering inside LOD expression

Tags: tableau-api

```
Product     Item    Status

A            aa     0

A           aaa     0

A           aaaa    0

A          aaaaa    1

B            bb     2

B           bbb     0

B           bbbb    3

C            cc     4

C           cccc    5
```

I need to calculate the count of items which have status = '0' at the Product level. So my output shall be:

```
Product Count

A                3

B                1
```

My formula is as follows:

```
{FIXED [Product]: CountD([Item) }
```

and I dragged the status into filters.

But this is not working. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{ FIXED [Product]:COUNT(IF [Status]=0 THEN [Status] END)}
```

Edit-------------------------------------------------------------

[image]